# Can't create Avro table in Dataproc 2.0 image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, avro, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to work with Hive with 2.0-debian10 image of Google Dataproc and can't create simple table with Avro format.

It's working fine with Parquet and also works fine with 1.5 image.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `db`.`avrotable`
(
  `a` INT
)
STORED AS avro;
```

Getting this error:

> ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 1, SQL state: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Unknown datum class: class org.codehaus.jackson.node.NullNode

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This failure is caused by [HIVE-24436](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-24436) issue and will be fixed in next release of Dataproc 2.0 image.